# What Lily Rank do I need for the Lily Rank trophies?

Tags: neptunia-v

So I need "max" Lily Rank for everyone x everyone for a plethora of trophies. I thought the "heart eyes" Lily Rank icon (starts at level 8) was the "max" but now I have someone with Lily Rank 10 (still heart eyes).

What is the numerical level of Lily Rank I need for the Lily Ranks? 8? 10? More?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the maximum Lily Rank you can get is 10 (the pink-colored one representing love).

Here's a list of all the Lily Ranks one can attain in this game:

- 0-1 = Hatred (purple colored)
- 2-3 = So-So (green colored)
- 4-5 = Neutral/OK (yellow colored)
- 6-7 = Like/Friend (orange colored)
- 8-10 = Love/Close Friend (pink colored)

However **to get the trophy all you need is lilly rank 8**, the first level of the pink icon.